# PHP PDO: Invalid parameter number

Tags: php, pdo

$emptyNumbers has 2 items and $qMarks is " ?,? ". What is the problem?

```
if(($key = array_search($row['nummer'], $emptyNumbers)) !== false) {
unset($emptyNumbers[$key]);
}
echo sizeof($emptyNumbers)."==>".$qMarks;  // 2 ==> ?,?
$qMarks = str_repeat('?,', count($emptyNumbers)-1) . '?';
$getPlayerData=$db->prepare( "SELECT number,surname,firstname,position,job FROM player WHERE nummer IN ($qMarks)");         
$getPlayerData->execute($emptyNumbers);

--> Error: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined
```

Comment: write only $getPlayerData->execute();

Comment: Then I get the error "no parameters were bound".

Comment: in which line you got error

Comment: no need to bound any parameter without bounding pdo work  as well as

Comment: It would be helpful if you would `var_dump($emptyNumbers);` and show us that output.

Comment: The error occurs in line 4 when I execute the query

Comment: var_dump prints: array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "3"
}

Comment: It could get an error because emptyNumber[1] is not filled. I'm gonna try it

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I previously unset values from $emptyNumbers and I did not reorder the array so that there were empty values.

```
if(($key = array_search($row['nummer'], $emptyNumbers)) !== false) {
unset($emptyNumbers[$key]);
//delete the gaps in the array!
$emptyNumbers = array_values($emptyNumbers);
}

$qMarks = str_repeat('?,', count($emptyNumbers)-1) . '?';
$getPlayerData=$db->prepare( "SELECT number,surname,firstname,position,job FROM player WHERE nummer IN ($qMarks)");         
$getPlayerData->execute($emptyNumbers);
```